# binding to list property of an object returns nothing mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, list, binding, properties

Context: ASP MVC 3/4, VB.net

I am trying to bind to an object that has a list property of complex type.
**Problem statement:** upon post back I get values in all the properties other than the complex type property, it is returned as nothing. I am doing something wrong because of which default model binder is not able to bind my property which is a list of complex type.

What am i doing wrong?

---

My View Model classes:

```
Public Class Customer  
    Public Property ID As Integer  
    Public Property FirstName As String  
    Public Property LastName As String          
    Public Appointments As IList(Of Appointment)  
End Class  

Public Class Appointment
    Public Property ClientName As String
    Public Property [Date] As DateTime
    Public Property TermsAccepted As Boolean
End Class
```

My action methods in controller look like this

```
    Function CreateCusotmerWithMultipleBookings() As ActionResult
        Dim Modeldata As New Customer With {.ID = 1, .FirstName = "First Name", .LastName = "Last Name"}
        Modeldata.Appointments = New List(Of Appointment) From {New Appointment, New Appointment, New Appointment}
        Return View(Modeldata)
    End Function

    <HttpPost()> _
    Function CreateCusotmerWithMultipleBookings(FormData As Customer) As ActionResult
        Return View(FormData)
    End Function
```

My view looks like this:

```
@ModelType Customer
@Using Html.BeginForm  
@Html.EditorForModel 
If Model.Appointments IsNot Nothing AndAlso Model.Appointments.Count > 0 Then
    For i As Integer = 0 To Model.Appointments.Count - 1
        @:<b >Appointment @i</b><br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(x) x.Appointments(i).ClientName) @:<br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(x) x.Appointments(i).Date) @:<br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(x) x.Appointments(i).TermsAccepted)@:<br />            
    Next
End If
End Using
```

HTML that gets generated from this view is something like: (I have removed unnecessary mark up to ease reading)

```
<body>
<form action="/testarea/Appointment/CreateCusotmerWithMultipleBookings" method="post">    
    <input id="ID" name="ID" type="number" value="1" />
    <input class="text-box single-line" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" value="First Name" />
    <input class="text-box single-line" id="LastName" name="LastName" type="text" value="Last Name" />
    <input id="Appointments_0__ClientName" name="Appointments[0].ClientName" type="text" value="" />
    <input id="Appointments_0__Date" name="Appointments[0].Date" type="text" value="1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM" />
    <input id="Appointments_0__TermsAccepted" name="Appointments[0].TermsAccepted" type="text" value="False" />
    <input id="Appointments_1__ClientName" name="Appointments[1].ClientName" type="text" value="" />
    <input id="Appointments_1__Date" name="Appointments[1].Date" type="text" value="1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM" />
    <input id="Appointments_1__TermsAccepted" name="Appointments[1].TermsAccepted" type="text" value="False" />
    <input id="Appointments_2__ClientName" name="Appointments[2].ClientName" type="text" value="" />
    <input id="Appointments_2__Date" name="Appointments[2].Date" type="text" value="1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM" />
    <input id="Appointments_2__TermsAccepted" name="Appointments[2].TermsAccepted" type="text" value="False" />
    <input type="submit" value="Create customer with multiple appointments" />
</form>
```

**Question again:**
Why does the formdata.Appointments in following controller has nothing value in it?

```
        <HttpPost()> _
    Function CreateCusotmerWithMultipleBookings(FormData As Customer) As ActionResult
        Return View(FormData)
    End Function
```